# How to make a window Borderless in haxeflixel?

Tags: haxeflixel

I want to make a borderless window in haxeflixel but I don't know how to?

I tried ading FlxG.borderless = true; but it is not reconized.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lime.ui.Window` to change the borderless property of the window.

```
package;

import flixel.FlxState;
import lime.ui.Window;

class FlixelState extends FlxState {
  override public function create() {
    Window.borderless = true;
  }
}
```

This should allow for your window have no top border on it.